# How do I return to previous areas in Hidden Folks?

Tags: hidden-folks

I accidentally advanced to the next level in Hidden Folks before finding every target in the area.

How can I return to previous areas to find people I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return to any level from the [main menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4iRG.png).

On the bottom bar, scroll all the way to the left, open the **Options** menu, then select **Menu**.

[image: Options Menu]